# Model validation error: EntityType has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I changed an attribute of my model from `string` to `CultureInfo`, and am now getting this error when I try to load any CRUD view (besides the `Create` form).

Error:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

MyProject.Models.CultureInfo: : EntityType 'CultureInfo' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
MyProject.Models.DateTimeFormatInfo: : EntityType 'DateTimeFormatInfo' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
CultureInfoes: EntityType: EntitySet 'CultureInfoes' is based on type 'CultureInfo' that has no keys defined.
DateTimeFormatInfoes: EntityType: EntitySet 'DateTimeFormatInfoes' is based on type 'DateTimeFormatInfo' that has no keys defined.
```

Model:

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class Project
    {
        public Project()
        {
            Sites = new List<Site>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Culture")]
        [UIHint("ProjectCulture")]
        public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }

        // (...)
    }
}
```

In `Application_Start()`:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ProjectDbContext>());
```

Looking at similar issues with the same error, I have not found a solution that worked for me. I assume there is a problem mapping `CultureInfo` with the Entity Framework, because the issue only appeared after I changed the type of this attribute, but *how can I solve this error without changing it back?*

Comment: Is `CultureInfo` a custom class? If not, you won't be able to store it. It is better to use a string column to store the culture, like "en-US, es-MX", etc. Then, you can convert the string into a CultureInfo object at run time

Comment: how does this data stored in your db? is it a single varchar column or a referenced table?

Comment: Fabio Luz: It is part of the `System.Globalization` package, and my own custom classes are mapped properly with all of their attributes. I do not see why it would be different in this case.

Comment: user2033402: It was stored as `nvarchar`, but after I deleted the table and tried to launch the project again, I received the same error and the table was not recreated, so I believe this was just a remnant of when I stored the culture as a `string`; it is not stored as anything, because the mapping is not done properly.

Answer (score 1):

by defining

```
public virtual CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }
```

you are indicating EF that you have a related table named CultureInfos: [EF convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx) for public virtual propertes is that that property is a navigation property.

You should continue to storing CultureInfo.Name as a string and then provide a getter property to retrieve the correponding CultureInfo object.

```
public string CultureName {get; set; }
public CultureInfo Culture {
    get { return new CultureInfo(CultureName); }
}
```

Comment: The same error is returned when `Culture` is not `virtual`, so why would that be the problem? It seems like you are commenting on two different issues, and as much as I appreciate the explanation on navigation properties, it does not answer my question.

Comment: What I mean is that EF will try to map CultureInfo entity to a database table, and CultureInfo properties to CultureInfos table fields. The error you're reporting is because EF can't infer a PK property for this 'entity'. Defining a cultureName property you have enough information for build at runtime the CultureInfo that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Define `[Key]` before defining the property for the primary key, e.g

```cs
[Key]
public int UserID { get; set; }
```